# Scala Play with Dotty

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, dotty

I've been having a look on how to get existing projects to use the Dotty compiler.

This has been straightforward for small projects following this.

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-example-project

This sets the scala version to 0.2.x. Which would mean that SBT could not find all the dependant libraries. However this can be sorted out by using `withDottyCompat`. This tells sbt to just go and get a 2.11 version. eg

```
eg ("org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "2.0.0").withDottyCompat()
```

All good so far. Where I'm stuck is to tell sbt to get play 2.11 versions of all the dependancies of a sbt plugin. Particularly Play! Eg

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "twirl-api" % "1.1.1"
```

I can't work out how to intercept this and ask sbt to download the 2.11 version of the play dependencies.

Anyone managed this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dependencies of an sbt-plugin", could you create a simple project on github that reproduces the problem? If the issue is that the sbt plugin is automatically adding dependencies to your project, you can change those by doing: `libraryDependencies := libraryDependencies.value.map(_.withDottyCompat())`

Comment: Thank you @GuillaumeMartres! I had to use "_.withDottyCompat(scalaVersion.value)" but it compiled and ran. I'll see how far I get